# Encrypt files on an SD card

Tags: windows-7, encryption

I have a new computer with a shiny slot for an SD card.  I have brought a nice fast 32GB SD card for it and will be using that as personal back up of my important documents.

What I hope to be able to do is create some sort of "service" that will encrypt the files and then copy them to the SD card.

What free software can I get that will encrypt the files (I need to use some of the standard encryption algorithms – AES type for the encryption) and what can I use to create the service?

I am running a Windows 7 64 bit Professional Edition, so Bitlocker is unavailable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org) to create an encrypted file container on your SD card, this will create a virtual drive which is encrypted. Then use [SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=15155) to syncronise the files/folders that you need to this encrypted drive.

Comment: Thank you. Does exactly what I had in mind.  Blowfish encryption and like the sync tool

Comment: TrueCrypt can also encrypt an entire volume, which is useful if you never want to store unencrypted files on the SD (i.e. it prevents mistakes).

Comment: SyncTool ... +1 :-)